# Cypress: error insert json => Special character sequence:

Tags: json, automated-tests, cypress

I'm trying to insert a json with a cypress test:

```
  cy.get('#exampleFormControlInput3').type("{'id':1904}", { commands: false })
```

but when I go to insert it it gives me the following error:
[image]

i modified the cypress.json as follows:

```
{
  ...
  ...
  ...
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "parseSpecialCharSequences":false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Arguments) writing `{{}` types `{`. So it should look like:

```
 cy.get('#exampleFormControlInput3').type("{{}'id':1904}")
```